# Installed Tesla gen 3 home charger with 60amp breaker and car pulling 48 amps. The conduit from charger to power panel is approx 4 ft

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, 120-240v, tesla

The conduit gets so hot you can't keep touching it.  The certified electrician used #6 THHN.  should #4 wire be used?

Comment: Conduit heats up only during charging

Comment: Type of conduit, metal or plastic?   #6 should be okay for 48 amps, but if conduit is that hot wondering if something else is the problem.  Bad connection or bad insulation.  The certified electrician should be called back to fix it.

Comment: @crip659 asked the type of conduit, which does matter. But also the **size** of the conduit. And is this #6 copper or aluminum? It should be copper because (a) for aluminum it needs to be #4 and (b) because AFAIK, Tesla chargers can't connect to aluminum. But sounds like bad connection.

Comment: @Ruskes What information did I state that is "bad" on Tesla charger? If it is about aluminum: From the [installation manual](https://www.tesla.com/support/charging/wall-connector/installing): "COPPER WIRE TERMINATIONS ONLY for landing in Wall Connector wirebox terminals. Conductors can be stranded or solid."

Comment: @Ruskes I fail to see what your complaint is about my statement. I said "must use copper to Tesla wall charger" - Harper's answer confirms that. I also said "aluminum needs to be #4" - Harper's answer confirms that. And to use #4 aluminum + polaris connectors to switch to copper for all of 4 feet - that makes no sense whatsoever (and in any case, that can't possibly be the case here because OP stated #6, just didn't say copper or aluminum". So please **explain** what my "bad" actually is.

Comment: There's at least one other DIY.SE question about current flowing through ground from their Tesla charger.  At a skim, I do not yet see a solution mentioned on that post: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274254/

Comment: Conduit is metal and wire is copper.  Electrician pulled new #6THHN copper thru conduit and still heats up.  I am thinking the ambient temp in garage is contributing to heat.

Answer (score 2):

EV charging is the most demanding electrical load in your home.  It is running the hardware at its  absolute thermal red-line limit for a continuous load.  The 6 AWG THHN is making full use of its 75°C (167°F) thermal limit in this application.

That is to say, the 60°C-rated "Romex" NM cable is not legal for 60A (at 6 AWG) because its insulation is not rated for a rise above 60°C (140°F or just into scalding).   (Implied: this wire running around 60°C is to be expected). Did the electrician do anything WRONG? Well no, there's a gold-standard for right and wrong, NEC, and I see no defect here unless the wire is not actually 6 AWG copper.

In fact, NEC is alright with with that same conduit accommodating three such charging circuits: see 310.15(B)(3)(a).

The only exception I would see is if you have high ambient temperature conditions - the standard derates assume ambient temperature of 30°C.  Phoenix attic, sunny side of dark painted house, etc. might warrant further thermal derates.

If you really, really, really want to "fix" it, then run 1/0 aluminum to a 60A breakered disconnect (reducing heating by 60% along that run) then then 4 AWG copper the last 2 feet to the Wall Connector (only 40% heat reduction, but only 2 feet).  I spec #4 because it's the largest that will fit on a Tesla Wall Connector v3.  I spec 1/0 aluminum because it's the largest that will fit on standard large-frame breakers, and you may have to use a 100A breaker to get there (hence the 60A disconnect).

### Not your grandfather's golf cart charger

When they designed this generation of EVs, SAE and Tesla recognized that "needing to get an electrical service upgrade to charge at home" would be a huge barrier for adoption of EVs. So into the charging standard they designed tech to make service upgrades unnecessary: the car can draw any amount of current based on a capacity signal from the wall unit (which is a GFCI switch, not a charger).

The wall unit can be set to transmit one ampacity always, or vary it "on the fly" as other appliances turn on.

Home charging is rife with misconceptions. Like the "1982 golf cart" logic that if it's rated for 48A charging, it must be provisioned 48A (ignoring the abovementioned tech).  Others greedily want the Fastest Charge Possible (tm).

### The charging speed you need

Thermal heating is the square of amps.  Double amps, quadruple heat and losses.

Technology Connections [has a fantastic video on home EV charging, and let me cue it up to the "level 2 charging speed" conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s).  Feel free to roll back for more stuff.

You only need to replace the miles you drove that day, + a 50% margin for recovery from unusual days.

Home charging can be like Uncle Ralph who owns a gas station, every night bringing over a 7 gallon can of gas and pouring as much as will fit into your tank. You leave full most days except after travel.  And after travel, you'd be tempted to "game it" by arriving home empty and letting Ralph catch you back up over the next few days, wouldn't you?

But like the video says, "The fastest charger is expensive, **and may come with more headaches than you bargained for**". And here you are with one of the *more minor* headaches we see.

### Cool your jets

Here we can borrow from Elon Musk via Wintergatan and their Magical Marble Machine (yes that thing works, not well) [in less than 2 minutes of this video](https://youtu.be/WN90HYiFpAw?t=33).

So I think the 48A was called out by a brilliant person, yet, I'm betting it's wild overkill for your home charging needs.  So I would propose to simply turn it down to 24A (half).  And then see where that puts you.   That's still charging over 200 miles a night on a Tesla.

My rule of thumb is: if a reduced charge rate actually, in the real world, forces you to seek public charging during ordinary in-town activities (can't count travel) then the charge rate is too low.  **But if it does not, it is not too low**.

That'll take care of the heating problem, and also, that heating isn't free, so you're saving some coin too.

And honestly for the vast majority of people, 16A would satisfy their needs.  On the more efficient Teslas, possibly even 12A.

Now, how do you turn it down?  Since your installation is actually safe and legal to 60A, you do not need to use the Wall Connector commissioning procedure to make this adjustment. You can simply use the Tesla's console inside the car.

(the setting in the Commissioning procedure is for when the cable has been downsized, e.g. #12 Romex for a 16A installation, and the EVSE **must not** exceed 16A.  UL requires that setting be inaccessible to the end user.)

Comment: Reducing the power draw from the EVSE just sounds like it is papering over the issue.  The conduit should not be getting hot because any wiring should be properly sized and free from damage to not cause heating.  There's almost certainly an issue with the install or there's been some kind of damage.  Given that this is a 60 amp circuit then this is might be outside of DIY territory and an electrician needs to be called.  I'm pretty comfortable with anything up to 30 or 40 amps but past experience with 50 amps tells me I should consider an electrician with anything that big.

Comment: @MacGuffin If OP's claim of 6 AWG is correct, there's no code problem here - so it's an aesthetic problem that rates an aesthetic solution. "The conduit should not be getting hot because any wiring should be properly sized and free from damage to **not cause heating**." I'm gonna need a Code citation on that one. Look at 310.14 et.seq. (Or 310.15 in the pre-2020 NEC) and there's a great deal about thermal ampacity ratings.  Crunch the numbers but it looks right to me, in fact it appears 2 more similar circuits could share the same pipe per 310.15(C)(1) former 310.15(B)(3)(a).

Comment: I'm not claiming there's a code violation.  I'm pointing out that if there's a concern on the wires getting too hot then there could have been some damage to the wires.  Perhaps there was damage during the install, or in the shipping of parts to the electrician.  If the heat coming off the conduit is normal then an electrician can verify that.  If this is not normal then the electrician that did the install should take on some responsibility for repairing the problem as there was damage not seen by the electrician in final inspection before calling it done.

Comment: @MacGuffin But a) in my experience I've never heard of any kind of wire damage which would cause that (other than the "Made in China" kind)... and b) heat over 60C is *within spec*, so there is no evidence of a problem NEC cares about.  Remember heat is proportional to amps **squared**. OP wants to run the wires within 7.7% of thermal limit, they're gonna get heat within 14.8% of thermal limit.  If they didn't, that would be alarming because it would mean the laws of physics have been suspended!!!

Comment: I don't know if there is evidence of a problem, only that the original concern is that the conduit is hotter than expected.  To know if this is in spec or not would require some measurement.  An electrician would have the tools to take that measurement, the homeowner might not.  If the homeowner has the right equipment and knowledge to do a proper DIY inspection then that's great.  If not then the professionals need to be called.  If there is a problem then the pros might still need to be called since the EVSE setup, or some other issue, is outside of DIY territory.

Answer (score -2):

If I saw that then I'd suspect a ground fault issue.

The current flow on the wires from the breaker box to the EVSE should be balanced, and that means the net magnetic field around the wires is cancelled out.  If there's a significant imbalance on the current flowing on the wires, as could happen if there's current flowing to ground somewhere outside the conduit, then there could be a magnetic field inducing a current on the steel conduit.  Steel isn't a great conductor, it's good but not great, so it is more prone to heating with current flowing through it.  This is steel, correct?  Some kind of metal?

The ground fault may be simpler than some induced voltage, the ground fault is flowing back to the breaker box through the steel conduit and heating it up.  Since this is heat that you feel and not an electrical shock then the voltage is close enough to ground potential that you feel only the heat.

If not a ground fault, and not undersized wiring (which a certified electrician is unlikely to do), then perhaps it is damaged wiring.  An incomplete break in some wire could produce heat that is conducted (thermal conduction, not electrical) to the steel would be felt on the outside surface.  This heating should be fairly local to that break, as in one spot on the conduit is hot but the rest is relatively cool.  That is likely a sign of a bigger failure later.  The wire could have been damaged as it was pulled through the conduit and left undetected in any testing done afterward.

One last thing in my "stream of consciousness" answer (I'm typing in possible problems as they pop in my head) is a very benign one.  The sun is heating up the conduit.  Is the conduit exposed to sunlight?

Whatever the cause I'd avoid touching it again until checked out.  Do you have any kind of heat sensor that doesn't require touching it?  My brother has an infrared thermometer that can check body temperature and such by just aiming it at the spot, it has a laser pointer or something to indicate where it is looking.  The point of light isn't *exactly* where it is looking as the light would influence the result so account for that if using such a device to monitor the conduit heating.  The electrician likely has one and will use it if there's a repeat visit to check on this.

I'd avoid touching the conduit again.  Whether this is a safety hazard that requires turning off the circuit at the breaker is something of a judgement call in my opinion.  And my opinion is worth precisely what you paid for it.  That's the thoughts from a sometimes electrical engineer and amateur electrician.

Comment: Could someone explain their reasons for the down votes?  I'd like to know how I could improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote but it's not a ground fault. Code requires a GFI breaker which would trip in that event. EV chargers don't always play nice with GFI breakers because they can have their own ground detection system which will cause the GFI breaker to trip so people do swap them out for a non-GFI breaker. It really sounds like undersized wiring. Most likely aluminium instead of copper.

Comment: @JD74 I'm not an expert on electrical code but I recall another answer on DIY.SE that pointed out EVSE do not require a GFCI breaker, and the answer spelled out how this meets code.  Also, it is possible the GFCI protection failed.  Even if the GFCI works properly that doesn't mean there isn't a ground fault that is somehow not detected by the breaker, could be some error in installation that prevents the protection from working.  I agree that a ground fault is unlikely but it is also the most probable explanation.  Undersized wire to the point of heating the conduit seems unlikely.

Comment: The EVSE itself is a GFCI, and will not permit an imbalance load to go into the car. Since the hardwired EVSE is a GFCI (receptacle) there is no need for a GFCI breaker.

Comment: A *properly functioning* GFCI will not permit an unbalanced load into the car.  Given the description there's a high probability that something is broken somewhere.  Maybe the heat coming off is normal, it's just in the head that this is "too hot".  The electrician should have some measure of liability here and want to make it right, give them a call and see what they say.